# Does Chrome store images on my local machine while viewing them?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I would like to ask, does Chrome store the images on my local machine when i'm viewing them online ? For example while i'm viewing images from Facebook or Instagram, are they being stored locally ?

If yes, where exactly are they being downloaded and is it possible to recover them  with a software if they were deleted ?

Comment: Yes. In your cache. Recover them with the recovery program of your choice.

Comment: You might find ChromeCacheView useful - https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Chrome store images on my local machine when I'm viewing them online?

Yes. In order to display any content as a web page (text, images, video, etc.), that content must first be downloaded in some form to the local PC so it can be shown to a user.

> If yes, where exactly are they being downloaded and is it possible to recover them with software if they were deleted?

All modern browsers use caching to minimize the amount of data they need to transfer from a remote web server. Caches are stored in different area of the computer for different browsers and different operating systems.

For instance, per the comment by @HelpingHand, [ChromeCacheView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) tells us Chrome's cache is located under `[User Profile]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache` for Windows 7. Windows XP, Windows 10, Mac and Linux all have different locations.

Regarding recovery, until a file is overwritten by other data, it is always potentially recoverable. A common misconception is that merely deleting a file is enough to make it unavailable in the future. Ease of recovery and possible damage to a file (due to partial overwriting), however, are always concerns.